# What does донный стрим mean?

Tags: значения

This phrase appears in the name of this Counter Strike video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTGisg5UPSE

Comment: _Стрим_ is nothing more than ‘[video] stream’. _Донный_ is definitely a sort of negative way to describe it. Most probably it’s an adjective from Russian _дно_ ‘bottom [of river, sea, some container]’.

Comment: Yes, for sure it’s from _дно_. _Дно_ (or even _днище_ with augmentative suffix) in gamers’ slang is a word for calling a person who is extremely bad gamer or his style of game. See e. g. [this thread](http://forum.worldoftanks.ru/index.php?/topic/442547-%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB/) on ‘World of Tanks’ forum.

Answer (score 6):

*Стрим* is nothing more than ‘[video] stream’.

*До́нный* is regular adjective from *дно́*. And *дно* – literal ‘bottom [of river, sea or some container]’ – is also as an epithet for something like abyss of despair / despondency / poverty / etc (cf. Russian classic play by Maxim Gorky titled *‘На дне’*).

But in gamers’ slang it somehow became a word for a person who is extremely bad gamer or his style of game.

A kind of Russian version of ‘Urbandictionary’ – teenslang.su – [defines *дно*](http://teenslang.su/id/12970) in this way:

> Дно,  -а, ср. (геймеры)
>   значение (1): оскорбление, попытка сказать что-то более страшное, чем слово нуб.
>   значение (2): в широком смысле — низшая степень чего-либо.
>   пример текста: *Яша, ты дно, нах ты бару брал, если ты им никуя не умеешь.*
>   синонимы: *нуб*.

Also you may take a look at for instance [this thread](http://forum.worldoftanks.ru/index.php?/topic/442547-%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB/) on forum of ‘World of Tanks’ (popular MMORPG in ex-Soviet Union).

*Дно* in that meaning is no less common with augmentative suffix *-ищ-* – *дни́ще*. Even more strong but still common phrase is *дни́ще ёбаное* (mat, yes).

P. S. Now I found an [article on Wikireality](http://wikireality.ru/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5) which explains the origin of term and says that it went beyond gamers’ slang, but it does not matter in a context of your question.